# Generate rsa keypair client-side (on the browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I need to know how to generate a rsa keypair on the cliente-side.

My system has to send encrypted data through the server and I have to ensure that the server cannot decrypt the data. So the Private/Public keypair cannot be generated on the server-side.

Any knowledge regarding this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Web Cryptography API](https://w3c.github.io/webcrypto/).

There's a specific [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey#rsa_key_pair_generation) on how to generate an RSA key pair:

```js
let keyPair = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: "SHA-256"
  },
  true,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
);
```